# Context menu does not respond to key press when opened from WindowsFormsHost

Tags: wpf, keyboard, contextmenu, windowsformshost

When focus is in a WindowsFormsHost and a context menu opens, the context menu does not respond to up/down arrow key presses.

The problem is illustrated by the following (almost self contained) code:

```
<Window x:Class="FocusAndWinformsSimple.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <DockPanel Name="DockPanel">
    <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="aaa"/>
        <MenuItem Header="bbb"/>
      </ContextMenu>
    </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox/>
      <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:MaskedTextBox/>
      </WindowsFormsHost>
    </StackPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

and code behind:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      InputBindings.Add(
        new KeyBinding(
          new RelayCommand(OpenContextMenu),
          new KeyGesture(Key.T, ModifierKeys.Control)));
    }

    void OpenContextMenu()
    {
      DockPanel.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = DockPanel;
      DockPanel.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
      DockPanel.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
  }
```

This will display two text boxes, a WPF and a WinForms. If you press Ctrl-T a simple context menu will appear.

Now run the program

1. Place the cursor in the WPF text box
2. Press Ctrl-T: the context menu appears
3. Press down-arrow: The first item in the context menu ('aaa') is selected.

whereas

1. Place the cursor in the WinForms text box
2. Press Ctrl-T: the context menu appears
3. Press down-arrow: Nothing happens

In our application, keyboard navigation is essential, so this is very annoying.

Can anybody help me explain? And preferably come up with a solution, making the second case work as the first.

(I have noticed, that normal menus - at least opened using mnemonics - work fine).

**UPDATE**

I guess, I should elaborate a bit on the real case, I'm working on: I have a TabControl where the content of each TabItem is developed elsewhere (but typically complex). My Ctrl-T context menu will show a list of the tab-item titles for quick navigation between tabs. (It mimicks the combobox to the right of tabs in Visual Studio).

Now, when the content of the present tab is a WPF control and focus is within the control, everything works fine. If you open the context menu and choose the same tab, focus will return to where it was before the context menu opened. This works since the context menu is a focus scope, so logical focus remains where it was within the control.

However, if the content is a WindowsFormHost, and focus is within, the context menu does not work as explained above. The first answer below fixes this by moving focus to any WPF control before opening the context menu. Unfortunately, this also changes logical focus making it impossible to reset it after the context menu closes.

I have tried to capture and save focus before changing focus and opening the context menu, with no luck.

The solution I have settled for is to change focus only when necessary. (checkin for `Keyboard.FocusedElement == null` seems to work). This means that my solution is only sub-optimal in the case where you have focus in a WinForms component, open the context menu and choose not to change tab. This is rare, so it is a great improvement over my first problem.

But I'm still curious to see whether a better solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your sample app and notice that when contextMenu is open with cursor in WPF textBox, the `logical focus` moves to contextMenu (cursor no more visible on textbox, hence keys working fine for context menu).

But however, when i tried it with maskedTextBox logical focus stays on textBox hence no keys working for ContextMenu.

So as a workaround i tweaked bit your code, see if this helps -

```
<DockPanel Name="DockPanel" Focusable="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
   .....     
</DockPanel>
```

Set `Focusable` of DockPanel to true and `FocusVisualStyle` to null so as to remove the dotted line around DockPanel on getting focus.

And now before opening the contextMenu,put logical focus manually on its placementTarget i.e. DockPanel like this -

```
void OpenContextMenu(object param)
{
   Keyboard.Focus(DockPanel);
   DockPanel.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = DockPanel;
   DockPanel.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
   DockPanel.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since its limitation of window forms textBox that it does not loose keyboard focus on context Menu opening.

> So we have to keep track if masked textBox had focus before opening
>   context menu then manually set focus on it once context menu is
>   closed.

*Code sample -*

```
<DockPanel Name="DockPanel" Focusable="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
  <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="aaa"/>
        <MenuItem Header="bbb"/>
      </ContextMenu>
   </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBox x:Name="txt"/>
      <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="msk"/>
      </WindowsFormsHost>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  InputBindings.Add(
    new KeyBinding(
      new RelayCommand<object>(OpenContextMenu),
        new KeyGesture(Key.T, ModifierKeys.Control)));
   msk.GotFocus += new EventHandler(msk_GotFocus);
   msk.LostFocus += new EventHandler(msk_LostFocus);
}

bool isFocusOnMaskedTextBox;
void msk_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   isFocusOnMaskedTextBox = false;
}

void msk_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   isFocusOnMaskedTextBox = true;
}

void OpenContextMenu(object param)
{
   bool moveFocusOnClose = isFocusOnMaskedTextBox;
   RoutedEventHandler eventHandler = null;
   eventHandler = (s, e) =>
   {
     if (moveFocusOnClose)
        msk.Focus();
     DockPanel.ContextMenu.Closed -= eventHandler;
   };
   if (moveFocusOnClose)
   {
      Keyboard.Focus(DockPanel);
   }
   DockPanel.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
   DockPanel.ContextMenu.Closed += eventHandler;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This workaround goes a long way to avoid the problem. It is, however, not perfect, as focus will not return to the textbox after the context menu closes.

Comment: I guess you have to put a hack for this, somewhat like what i did in my answer. Since for Winforms control there is no seperate logical and keyboard focus. And i tried it in the sample app, its working fine.